# Creating a redirect in Angular Dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have two views, `about.html` and `bio.html` and would set up a redirect from the first to the second. I would expect the following to work, but it doesn't. Any idea why?

Here is the controller code:

```dart
# my_controller.dart
@NgController(
    selector: '[my-controller]',
    publishAs: 'ctrl'
)
class MyController {
  Router router;

  MyController(this.router);

  redirect() {
    router.go('bio', {});
  }
}
```

And here is the relevant excerpt from index.html:

```dart
# index.html
<div my-controller>
  <span><a href="#/about" ng-click="ctrl.redirect()">About</a></span>
  <section>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </section>
</div>
```

And here is the router code:

```dart
# my_router.dart
library my_router;

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

class MyRouteInitializer implements RouteInitializer {
  init(Router router, ViewFactory view) {
    router.root
      ..addRoute(
          name: 'about',
          path: '/about',
          enter: view('views/about.html'))
      ..addRoute(
          name: 'bio',
          path: '/bio',
          enter: view('views/bio.html'));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `href="#/about"` from the link. It's conflicting with the programmatic redirect to `bio`.

Comment: Of course. Thanks.  Looking at the code again, this type of redirect has limited value. If the user clicks a different link in the app that goes to #/about.html', or if the user has bookmarked that link, there will be no redirect.